# Inserting Value into a List with designated position

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a function that when called, takes a list, value, and insert position, and returns a copy of the list with the value inserted at the place specified by the insert position. For this task (due to request), I'm unable to use bulit in functions (other than range(), slice expressions, list methods (apart from append()) or string methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):

 new_list = []
 for i in my_list:
     new_list.append(i)

 if insert_position > length(my_list):
     new_list.append(value)
     return new_list
 elif insert_position <= 0:
     new_list.append(value[0])
     return new_list

str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = list_function.insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished very simply using slice notation.

You known what your function needs to do. *Insert a given value into a given position in a given list*. Basically, you need to split the list into two parts. The first part contains all the elements ***before*** the given index. The second part contains all the elements ***after*** the given index. Once you have those two parts, you can simply "sandwich" the given value in between.

Here is visual demonstrating what I mean. Assume the index is equal to `1`:

```
  first part      value             second part
     |              |                    |
    [1]-------------2----------------[3][4][5]
     |                                   |
     |                                   |
     |                                   |
     + all elements *before* index 1     + all elements *after* index 1
```

Here is how the implementation would look like:

```
>>> def insert_value(lst, value, idx):
...     # elements before idx
...     front = lst[:idx]
...     # elements after idx
...     back = lst[idx:]
...     # "sandwhiching" the value between the front and back parts
...     return front + [value] + back
```

example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 3, 4, 5]
>>> insert_value(lst, 2, 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

I'm not exactly sure if you have to, but it would be trivial to implement a check to see if the given index is in the bounds of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

## A more understandable one

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    if insert_position <= 0:
        new_list.append(value)
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    elif insert_position >= len(my_list):
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
        new_list.append(value)
    else:
        new_list = [None] * (len(my_list) + 1)
        # replace : index = [i for i in range(len(new_list)) if i != insert_position]
        index = []
        for i in range(len(new_list)):
            if i != insert_position:
                index.append(i)
        # end
        new_list[insert_position] = value
        for i in index:
            # replace : new_list[i] = my_list[i if i < insert_position else i - 1]
            if i < insert_position:
                new_list[i] = my_list[i]
            else:
                new_list[i] = my_list[i - 1]
            # end
    return new_list
```

---

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    if insert_position <= 0:
        new_list.append(value)
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    elif insert_position >= len(my_list):
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
        new_list.append(value)
    else:
        new_list = [None] * (len(my_list) + 1)
        index = [i for i in range(len(new_list)) if i != insert_position]
        new_list[insert_position] = value
        for i in index:
            new_list[i] = my_list[i if i < insert_position else i - 1]
    return new_list
```

Comment: @sylvoo112 it creates an empty list with length of `len(my_list) + 1`, more understandable, creates an empty list with length greater than `my_list` by 1.

Comment: Would there be another way to write it without using [None]?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, given that you're inserting a single value:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0, insert_position)
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
    new_list.append(value)
    for i in range(insert_position, len(my_list)+1)
        new_list.append(my_list[i-1])
```

If you can use splicing and append, then

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = my_list[:insert_position]
    new_list.append(value)
    new_list = new_list+my_list[insert_position:]
```

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(my_list)+1):
    if i < insert_position:
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
    elif insert_position == i:
        new_list.append(value)
    else:
        new_list.append(my_list[i-1])
return new_list
str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
print(new_list)
```